# S3 Authenticate User without Secret Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a user with read access on a bucket. Is there a way to authenticate with the users' credentials without using my secret key?

Something like (pseudo code):

```
auth = new S3Authentication(user, pass)
obj = S3::getObject(obj, auth)
```

**Update**
I discovered the solution to my own question. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original reason for asking this question was because I was operating under the assumption that the global access and security key needed to be use to generate the appropriate [Authorization digest header](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html).

This is not the case.

You can use Amazon's IAM to create a new key pair to use when authenticating. Here are the steps:

- Create a new Group in IAM
- Set the policy on the group to whatever you access you want users within this group to have. In my case, I just chose the S3 Read-Only policy template
- Create a new user and put it in this group

Creating a new user will generate a new secret/access key specific to that user. You can use this pair to auth S3 transactions.

As an aside, you shouldn't need to mess with the bucket-specific permissions. In my case, I have no bucket permissions set (not even Authenticated users) and it works just fine.